# How to compress the distribution js files in angular2 and do versioning to js files

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How to compress the angular2 all distribution files. I have main.bundle.js (16MB), polyfill.js, and inline.bundle.js. How to compress these js further and version them. Also how can we use the webpack explicitly other then inbuilt webpack. Does any one know about this. I am also using the build optimizer in my ng build command after distribution files size creates is 16MB for main.bundle.js.

Comment: try `ng build --prod` 16MB is wayyy to large

Answer (score 0):

```
ng build --prod
```

...automatically downsizes your bundles and integrates a unique id into the filename. 
This unique id helps to prevent problems with browser caching when you deploy a new version. It also helps you to do a versioning.
In Angular 4 you can add '--build-optimizer' (CLI 1.3 and later) to the command to get some more shrinking. With Angular 5 it's enabled by default.